# i have a issue in parse php sdk

Tags: php, parsing, parse-server

I want to retrieve all data from back4app and show it in laravel php application, but I'm facing an error when I compact $result into a view.

The error is "array to string conversion" and code returns a lot of objects. I don't know how I loop them in a foreach clause.

The laravel code:

```
public function getplaterating()
{
   //i dnt have connection problem connection is working
    ParseClient::setServerURL('https://parseapi.back4app.com', '/');

    $query = new ParseQuery("PlateRating");
    $query->equalTo("All",true);
    $results = $query->find();
    return print_r($results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this PHP SDK documentation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/#basic-queries), you can do something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
  $object = $results[$i];
  echo $object->getObjectId() . ' - ' . $object->get('name');
}
```

Comment: thanks but now i have another question how can i get all data with parse sdk like i have a class platerating and i want to retrieve all data

Comment: It is not so clear what you want to accomplish. Could you please open a new question and add some code?